# curl_setopt(): You must pass either an object or an array with the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER

Tags: php

У меня был сайт на одном хостинге и домене, но по стечению обстоятельств все перенес на другой домен и хост, и один из скриптов php перестал работать, хотя все идентичное и рабочее. Вот это строка `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 'User-Agent: '.getallheaders()['User-Agent']);` пишет вот такую ошибку curl_setopt(): You must pass either an object or an array with the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, и соответственно дальше проскакивают ошибки Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by. Скрипт 100% рабочий, пользовался им на прошлом домене и хосте, как перенес вылезла вот это ошибка, в чем дело ума не приложу. Эта строка кода в контексте

```
$ch = curl_init('https://testsite.ru/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 'User-Agent: '.getallheaders()['User-Agent']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $pass);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$session = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

То что там testsite не обращайте внимание, намеренно изменил, вообщем подскажите почему на прошлом домене и хосте все работало а на этом такая ошибка, как исправить?

Comment: вы прочитали, что написано в сообщении об ошибке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что принимает массив аргументов(ошибка на это как бы и намекает), а вы передаете строку.

Цитирую документацию:

> `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`  Массив устанавливаемых HTTP-заголовков, в формате
>   `array('Content-type: text/plain', 'Content-length: 100')`

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-setopt.php